# Checking the arrays content. How to see if element value appears two or more times?

Tags: arrays, conditional-statements

I need to write a program which prompts user to type 10 int values, and then it checks if any value is typed more than once. If it is typed more than once, it needs to be ignored and displayed only once. If it is typed only once, it is OK.

for example(if array.length is 5), 
input: 1 2 2 3 4 5
outputs: 1 2 3 4 5

anybody knows the deal ? 
thanks

Comment: What language are you trying to write this on? JS?

Answer (score 0):

In Java it can be easily done with `Set<String>` type.

But, as Crisyian have said, you should specify language in question and in tags.